# Converting string from VB.NET to C# with double quoted and backslash

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

I am having a hard time converting my string correctly from vb.net to C#.

String should output like the one from vb.net. Any help will be appreciate.

This is the vb.net string

```
Dim cmdS As String = "-on """ & path & """ -ot file -actn ace -ace ""n:DOMAIN\" & user & ";p:change"""
```

on debug the string look like this

```
"-on "\\lex-data\Home\Thth" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:DOMAIN\thth;p:change""
```

now in C# I try this

```
string cmdS = "-on \"" + path + "\" -ot file -actn ace -ace \"n:DOMAIN\\" + username + ";p:change\"\"";
```

Output from c#

```
"-on \"\\\\\\\\lex-data\\Home\\Thth\" -ot file -actn ace -ace \"n:DOMAIN\\thth;p:change\"\""
```

I try other string variant but its worst it add more backslash.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? is that vb to c# conversion practice issue?

Comment: where is the difference to vb.net? what is the desired output? I only see the double "" at the end (you did 2 in C# but only one in vb.net)

Comment: yeah i try convert it from vb to c#

Comment: If you are viewing the C# string in the debugger then it includes the escaping characters.  The VB debugger does not since it doesn't use them.  The "actual" string will not include them, so it appears that the output you're seeing is correct.

Comment: i try to make it look like the one output from vb.net because the string is use has a process command and mine in c# doesn't get accept

Comment: I would recommend that you research and or lookup examples on how to use the `string.Format()` function and use `{0}{1}{2}...etc` format to build the parameter list..

Answer (score 2):

VB.Net uses double quotes as escape character, but C# uses backslash. So in your VB.Net string, we need to find out which double quotes are used as escape characters. By analyzing output string (above question) in VB.Net, there are four (4) double quotes in the string (by ignoring the outer quotes), it means VB.Net used four double quote characters as escape characters, so by replacing those four double quotes by backslashes (in C#) we get the string in C#.

```
string str2 = "-on \"" + path + "\" -ot file -actn ace -ace \"n:DOMAIN\\" 
              + user + ";p:change\"";
```

Now in C#, backslash is used as escape character, so backslash are used twice when we want to print single backslash. Check this string

```
string alpha = "Path to the verses folder D:\\Data\\Islamic\\verses";
```

In output, it will eliminate the a backslash in each couple

Comment: I updated the answer @stakx, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can place @ before the string and produce VB like strings using double quoting.  New lines are also available in this syntax as return key.

ex:

```
    string str = @"Here is a quote "" 
and a new line";
```

Comment: which for his would be: `string cmdS = @"-on """ + path + @""" -ot file -actn ace -ace ""n:DOMAIN\" + user + @";p:change""";` if I did it correctly